# Algolia + React Native InstantSearch (SortBy)

Tags: react-native, algolia, instantsearch

I need to sort Algolia results by always putting featured at the top of results around a location (no UI for this, just always does it). Is there a way to do this like an empty `<VirtualRefinementList attribute="brand" />` in their [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/native/react/) / what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this thing by changing the configurations in the Algolia dashboard. There are several options the `filtering and facets` which can help you!